# Sorting a vector of vectors in Clojure

Tags: sorting, vector, clojure

I want to sort this vector of vectors (of vectors) `[[[5 5] [4 4] [8]] [[8 8] [2 2] [3]]]` in descending order, so it becomes
`[[[8 8] [2 2] [3]] [[5 5] [4 4] [8]]]`

For clarity, `[[[5 5] [4 4] [3]] [[5 5] [4 4] [8]]]` would become
`[[[5 5] [4 4] [8]] [[5 5] [4 4] [3]]]`

The following doesn't work, not sure why:

```
(sort-by > [[[5 5] [4 4] [8]] [[8 8] [2 2] [3]]])
```

After many tries and research I'm at the same point, can someone help?

Comment: Such sorting has a lot of corner cases. E.g. how do you compare `[[1 1]]` to `[[1] [1]`? But to reverse some sorting that already works, you can supply a comparator that exchanges its arguments: `(sort-by some-key-fn #(compare %2 %1) data)`.

Comment: `compare` already can handle those corner cases, and so `sort` already works. Your example could supply `identity` as the `key-fn` and it would work. But you can simply use `sort` directly with your modified comparator, as I elaborate in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re very close, and you have already noticed that `sort` in Clojure is general enough to handle vectors. The problem is that `sort-by` with three arguments is not what you want, that is trying to use `>`  as a `key-fn` that will be called on each element before sorting, and calling `>` with a single argument trivially returns `true`, so no sort is performed.

But if you look at `(doc sort)` you can see that there is a three argument arity of `sort` itself that does what you want:

```
clojure.core/sort
([coll] [comp coll])
  Returns a sorted sequence of the items in coll. If no comparator is
  supplied, uses compare.  comparator must implement
  java.util.Comparator.  Guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will
  not be reordered.  If coll is a Java array, it will be modified.  To
  avoid this, sort a copy of the array.
```

Trying that using `>` as our comparison doesn’t work, though, because `>` deals with numbers, not vectors:

```
(sort > [[[5 5] [4 4] [3]] [[5 5] [4 4] [8]]])
Execution error (ClassCastException) at java.util.TimSort/countRunAndMakeAscending (TimSort.java:355).
class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Number is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

But we can use the `compare` function that was mentioned in a comment on your question with `sort` to achieve your goal. `compare` is what `sort` normally uses, and it can handle vectors, but it sorts in the wrong order, so we want to swap the order of the elements we are comparing:

```
(sort #(compare %2 %1) [[[5 5] [4 4] [3]] [[5 5] [4 4] [8]]])
([[5 5] [4 4] [8]] [[5 5] [4 4] [3]])
```

Comment: According to the first paragraph of OP's question together with this answer, the following should work: `(assert (= (sort #(compare %2 %1) [[[8 8] [2 2] [3]] [[5 5] [4 4] [8]]]) [[[5 5] [4 4] [8]] [[8 8] [2 2] [3]]]))`. However, this assertion fails for me. Are you sure we have properly understood OP's question?

Comment: @Rulle I think you have switched around the argument and the expected result in your assert there. Above answer holds for both examples of OP for me.

Comment: Thanks James Elliot, that works fine.  You were right I was close, I already saw that compare works, but I didn't know how to combine it with sort. Too tender still on Clojure...